# How do I understand which version is supported by a module?

Tags: community-official-site

I want to use the APIs described in [REST and other APIs](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/apis/rest-and-other-apis) to understand which Drupal versions are supported by a module.

So far, I tried with https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node.json?field_project_machine_name=ctools, but it doesn't return any information about the supported Drupal version.

How can I retrieve the Drupal version with which a module is compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal versions with which a module like the *Chaos Tool Suite (ctools)* module is compatible is listed in https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/current, for each module releases. That API is described in [Update status XML](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/apis/update-status-xml).

For example, the following XML tags are saying that release 8.x-3.6 is compatible with Drupal 8.8 and Drupal 9. The value is set from the project maintainers; it's not a value set by tools able to determine the Drupal versions with which a module is compatible.

```xml
<name>ctools 8.x-3.6</name>
<version>8.x-3.6</version>
<tag>8.x-3.6</tag>
<status>published</status>
<release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/releases/8.x-3.6</release_link>
<download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ctools-8.x-3.6.tar.gz</download_link>
<date>1620832812</date>
<security covered="1">Covered by Drupal's security advisory policy</security>
<core_compatibility>^8.8 || ^9</core_compatibility>
```

https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/current shows only the releases compatible with Drupal 8 or newer versions. For Drupal 7, the URL is https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/7.x, but that doesn't show the exact Drupal 7 version the module is compatible with.

```xml
<name>ctools 7.x-1.19</name>
<version>7.x-1.19</version>
<tag>7.x-1.19</tag>
<version_major>1</version_major>
<version_patch>19</version_patch>
<status>published</status>
<release_link>https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools/releases/7.x-1.19</release_link>
<download_link>https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ctools-7.x-1.19.tar.gz</download_link>
<date>1611988841</date>
<mdhash>57a6bb37a3d69c51170212802e728951</mdhash>
<filesize>451495</filesize>
<security covered="1">Covered by Drupal's security advisory policy</security>
```

Since the release name starts with *7.x-*, that release is compatible with Drupal 7.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: A possible extension to this question, maybe if you can help would be great:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303428/extract-more-data-on-field-collection-item-from-rest-apis-of-drupal